# how to transfer the value of one textfield to the other with material UI in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, state

I wanna transfer the content from one text field (embedded in a dialog window) to another text field (not embedded).

The current result is "object Object" (instead of the text field value). Do you know why it does not work?

I created two different states within a functional component. The function "setOriginalTextValue" should transfer the value of one state to the other :

```
export default function FormDialog() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const [dialogValue, setDialogValue] = React.useState();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleDialogValueChange = (event) => {
    setDialogValue({
      dialogValue: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const setOriginalTextValue = () => {
    setValue({
      value: dialogValue,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="text" color="inherit">
        <TextField
          id="outlined-multiline-static"
          label="Frage"
          multiline
          onClick={handleClickOpen}
          rows={4}
          value={value}
          placeholder="hello"
          onChange={handleClickOpen}
          variant="outlined"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
          }}
        />
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onExit={setOriginalTextValue}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>Please type the text in here</DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="ChatbotTexxt"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            onChange={handleDialogValueChange}
            fullWidth
            onExit={console.log("the dialog  value", dialogValue)}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're setting objects, but expect strings instead. Try this change:

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

const handleDialogValueChange = (event) => {
    setDialogValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const setOriginalTextValue = () => {
    setValue(dialogValue);
  };
```

`useState` setters like these expect the direct value, as they already 'know' the variable name, since it's their only responsibility.